# How can I create a Table of Contents automatically in a Sharepoint 2007 wiki page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2007, wiki, tableofcontents

As our users get more familiar with the wiki functionality, and like it, we see that pages are getting longer and more difficult to navigate.

We would like to be able to generate table of contents on a per-wiki-page basis to allow easier navigation, i.e. the users create content whose hierarchy is represented by h2/h3/h4 elements and then the TOC is automatically generated at the top of the wiki page with each entry in the TOC being a link to the corresponding h2/h3/h4 element in the page.

We do not have access to Sharepoint Designer so any funny stuff will have to involve css/javascript inserted using a Content Editor Web Part.

Best regards,

Colm O'Gairbhith

Comment: In case this may be useful to anyone else, I ended up using the jquery [tableofcontents plugin](http://fuelyourcoding.com/scripts/toc/)

Answer (score 1):

In case this may be useful to anyone else, I ended up using the jquery [tableofcontents](http://fuelyourcoding.com/scripts/toc/) plugin.

The tutorial [Automatically Generate Table of Contents with jQuery](http://www.codingwhiz.com/jqueryui/automatically-generate-table-of-contents-with-jquery.html) explains how to use this.

Comment: can you provide a short walkthrough on how to do it? from importing libraries to generating the ToCs? Thanks

Comment: Another option is the [jQuery TOC plugin](http://projects.jga.me/toc/), or the [Smooth TOC plugin](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/jquery-plugin-smooth-scrolling/).